# Unwanted Infinite While Loop with Python 3

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite

```
v0=1
alpha=1
t=0
dt=0.1
v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
while v > 0:
    print(v,t)
    v0 = v
    t = t+dt
```

My intention is that after the first check that v>0 we have v0 equal to v before the check is re-performed.
Instead I'm presented with an infinite stream of the first calculated v = 0.9

Comment: you never update v....

Comment: never modified v inside the loop so if v is positive it remains positive

Comment: You change `v0`, but never use that value.  You never change `v`.  You change `t`, but never use it or test it.  Please refer to a tutorial on loops and repair your logic.  At the very least, explain clearly what you *think* your loop logic should do.

Comment: Your pre-loop assignment to `v` doesn't mean that the value of `v` changes as the value of `v0` changes; you might want to move that line *into* your loop, so it updates with each iteration.

Comment: Apologies. I want my loop to print (velocity, time) until the velocity, v, is no longer greater than 0.

Comment: But you never change `v` ... how is it supposed to get from 0.9 to non-positive?

Comment: Because v would decrease with each updated v0 value

Comment: How does it decrease?  You never assign to it within the loop.  That's the crux of this matter, I think.  See the two (nearly identical) posted answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recalculate `v` each time through the loop, using your updated parameters:

```
import numpy as np

v0=1
alpha=1
t=0
dt=0.1
v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt

while v > 0:
    print(v,t)
    v0 = v
    t = t+dt
    v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
```

Output:

```
0.9 0
0.805131670195 0.1
0.715402540577 0.2
0.630821068577 0.30000000000000004
0.551396823627 0.4
0.477140724644 0.5
0.408065350983 0.6
0.34418535795 0.7
0.28551804525 0.7999999999999999
0.232084156635 0.8999999999999999
0.183909043077 0.9999999999999999
0.141024425429 1.0999999999999999
0.103471206469 1.2
0.0713042659134 1.3
0.0446014072812 1.4000000000000001
0.0234823620184 1.5000000000000002
0.00815840625677 1.6000000000000003
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v0=1
alpha=1
t=0
dt=0.1
v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
while v > 0:
    print(v,t)
    v0 = v
    t = t+dt
    v = v0 - alpha*np.sqrt(v0)*dt
```